# What is the difference between an unsigned short and a USHORT?

Tags: c++, variables

What is the difference between `USHORT` and an `unsigned short` and when would you use each?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

USHORT is a macro which is not part of the official C++ language (it's probably defined or typedef'ed somewhere). unsigned short is an official type defined by the C++ language as an integer that can at least hold numbers between 0 and 65535.

Use unsigned short and your code will be portable - don't use USHORT unless you company's coding standard requires it.

Comment: Note that a `typedef` is not a macro.

Comment: i was looking at some sample code here:http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/17053/ in the first code block. Could you take a look and see if you can figure out why they use it?

Comment: @stas: it's just a Microsoft'ism, something done without any other reason than that other's doing it. It's about the same as the C'ism of writing `void foo(void)`, when in C++ there is no point to the second `void`, the one in the argument list. Or the Java`ism of writing `double getSin()`, when in C++ the `get` has no purpose and is just visual noise. Cheers,

Comment: @stas Looks like Microsoft C++ to me - this is a particular style adopted by the Windows guys and the Microsoft compiler defines those types. If you are working in code like this - it is usually conventional to follow the style of existing code.

Answer (score 2):

`unsigned short` is a standard [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) expression and USHORT is not. The precise definition can be found in the Wikipedia article *[Integer (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29)*.

Sometimes, we typedef unsigned short USHORT in the header. Then USHORT can be used as well as unsigned short.